# is it possible to store a users input in a new variable after each while loop iteration

Tags: c++

As the question stated before is it possible to store the input from the user into a new || next variable after each while loop iteration.

for example

```
double average;
double test0, test1, test2,test3, test4;

while (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){

cout << "Enter a test score" << endl;
cin >> test0... net iteration is test1.....test2 endl;

}
```

or would it make more sense to store the test scores in an array?

Comment: No, it's not possible. Use a `std::vector` or a `std::map` if you insist you need a variable name.

Answer (score 2):

That's why we have std::vector http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector ... cin into a temporary variable then push it in.